# Catch the alert view of the VLCMobileKit For iOS

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

In my swift project, I implement a VLC Player and an activity indicator in it. And every time when I load remote streaming video failed, it will popup a alert view said `Your input can't be opened`. I want to catch this alertView and stop my activity indicator, but don't know how.

I've search all the delegate, like VLCMediaDelegate and VLCMediaPlayerDelegate, all of it can't reach my requirement.

Could someone tell me how to stop the activity indicator when alert show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out a solution for this.
Add ViewController as VLCMediaPlayerDelegate, and implement the method `mediaPlayerStateChanged`

Inside this method, I found that when the alert popup, the state of VLCPlayer will equal 0!

The code is like this:

```
public func mediaPlayerStateChanged(aNotification: NSNotification!) {
    if self.vlcPlayer.state.rawValue == 0
    {
        liveLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

Hope this could help someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877371/212834) (Swift-ified):

```
var player: VLCMediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer(options: ["--extraintf="])
```

I had previously compiled it myself, like the accepted answer, but that's a PITA.

Comment: Hi, this method only disable the alertView. I want to catch the AlertView when it shows up.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I had a few tabs open and didn't re-read this question thoroughly enough once I found a solution to my problem.