# How to disminss an UIAlertView which not create by myself via program in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am developing in Objective-C , and I use the **VLC library** in my project.

Sometime , When **VLC Player** has error happened , it will show an `UIAlertView` like the following picture:

[image]

But the above `UIAlertView` is create and show by VLC library. The one way to dismiss the `UIAlertView` is click the `OK button`.

How do I dismiss the `UIAlertView` by program  ?

Comment: Do you can handle this alert? Other way, do you have any pointer point to this alert?

Comment: @anhtu I can not handle this alert...Can I detect which `AlertView` is active ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to VLClibrary.m and delete below code

```
@"--extraintf=ios_dialog_provider"];
```

clean the code and recompile. 
you are good to go.

Checkout this links for futher details: 
[How to disable VLCMediaPlayer error AlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083068/how-to-disable-vlcmediaplayer-error-alertview)